# How would you convert List<T> to Vector<T> C#

Tags: c#, .net, list, vector, system.numerics.vectors

I'm using the vectors C# library `using System.Numerics;`
I need to convert List to a Vector

I've tried implicitly and explicitly converting the type but it does not have inbuilt compatibility.
I have read the documentation looking for a method that can do do this conversion, but didn't find any suitable.

I know I could achieve this conversion using a simple for loop but doing this conversion many times within my program seems terribly inefficient and I'm wondering if anyone knows of a better way to get the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Vector<T>` has a [constructor which takes a `Span<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-numerics-vector-1-ctor(system-span((-0)))), and [`CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.interopservices.collectionsmarshal.asspan?view=net-6.0#system-runtime-interopservices-collectionsmarshal-asspan-1(system-collections-generic-list((-0)))) lets you get a `Span<T>` from a `List<T>`.

E.g.:

```
var list = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
var vector = new Vector<int>(CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan(list));
```

[See on SharpLab](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghglgdgNAFxAJwK7wCYgNQB8ACADAAT4CMALANwCwAUEaWQHQByqYApslAMYDOtBiXLMASugRQuzAJIwE3APYAHAMrcAbn06D69TRGTEANlH4JiAXmIxOAd2IAZcwgA8sBAD4AFAEpiAG9iMjhiACYwgGYwijCAVjCANjCAdjCADmIAXyFDY01OXgQlYxs7RwA1IpLkDwVfAGElExMaqCUYfgBZI34ACwgTZgBBfjUVCBgfMws/Pzya0uYAEQ4VfyEgA===).

This results in a single memory copy from the contents of the array backing the `List<T>`, to the memory backing the `Vector<T>`.

Heed the warnings in the docs for `CollectionsMarshal.AsSpan`: it returns a reference to the array which is *currently* backing the `List<T>`, but that will change if the list is updated. For just taking a snapshot for copying into a `Vector<T>`, however, it's fine.

Comment: Thank you worked perfectly!